# Mi código funciona en una página web, pero mi pc no puede compilar el código

Tags: c

Mi problema es el siguiente, me pidieron hacer una lista de 1 millón de números random y que el numero random generado fuese del 0 al 100. e incluirlos en una lista. hasta ahí correcto, cuando copilo el código con 10, 1.000, o 100.000 valores en la lista por ejemplo se ejecuta perfecto, pero cuando lo trato de compilar con el valor que se me dio de 1 millón, mi PC al compilarlo devuelve un valor de memoria y simplemente no lo hace, pero cuando uso la página web [replit](https://replit.com/) puedo correr el código y generar el millón que me piden, entonces me surgió la duda si es por culpa de mi pc que no puedo copilar este código o quizás mi código tiene algo mal.

Lo otro que me parece extraño es que cuando lo hago en otro lenguaje como python si puedo crear un millón de valores en una lista, aunque puede que esto sea porque python no es un lenguaje compilado, pero sinceramente no sé porque ocurre esto.

el código:

```
int lista(int x){
  int lis[x];
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    lis[i] = rand()%(100-1)+1 ;
    printf("%d",lis[i]);
    printf(" ");
  }
  return 0;

}

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int x;
  printf("cantidad de números aleatorios a generar: ");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  lista(x);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lo más posible es que tu equipo no pueda ejecutar tantas líneas de código con la memoria RAM que tengas, comprueba si puedes asignarle más RAM a tu entorno de desarrollo

Comment: Dices "_al compilarlo devuelve un valor de memoria y simplemente no lo hace_" ¿puedes ser más concreto/a? Qiuzás la clave está en el mensaje que te muestra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos errores en tu código, uno ya lo ha señalado [Pedro González](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/523123/2742) en su respuesta: estás pidiendo demasiada memoria en el [heap de función](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mont%C3%ADculo_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

```
int lista(int x){
  int lis[x]; // <--- Si 'x' es demasiado grande, se desborda el heap.
```

El segundo error es que no puedes usar variables para definir el tamaño de formaciones<sup>1</sup> en el heap, se requiere que el tamaño sea un valor conocido en tiempo de compilación pero `x` sólo se conoce en tiempo de ejecución.

La solución es pedir memoria de la pila (no del heap):

```
int lista(int x){
  int *lis = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * x); // Pedir memoria.
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    lis[i] = rand()%(100-1)+1 ;
    printf("%d",lis[i]);
    printf(" ");
  }
  free(lis); // Liberar memoria.
  return 0;
}
```

Pero yo iría un paso más allá, tal y como está tu código ni siquiera necesitas la "lista":

```
void lista(int numeros) {
  for(int indice = 0; i < numeros; ++numeros){
    printf("%d ", rand() % 101); // Modulo contra 101 da numeros entre 0 y 100
  }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 1):

La memoria dentro de una función se reserva en el heap y el tamaño de este está limitado, aunque se puede cambiar con las directivas de compilación. Por ejemplo, si en tu compilador tienes configurado un heap de 1MB, cuando reservas memoria para tu variable lis con un valor x grande, esta superará el tamaño del heap y por eso te da un error.

Prueba a reservar la memoria dinámicamente, ya que esta se toma del total disponible para la aplicación. Cambia la línea

*int lis[x];*

por

int *lis = (int *)malloc(x * sizeof(int));

Cuando ya no necesites más la memoria, deberás liberarla para que tu aplicación no acabe consumiendo toda la memoria. En este caso, antes de salir de la función, antes del return, tienes que añadir

*free(lis);*

Otra cosa, ya que tu función devuelve un valor que no se utiliza, puedes declararla como void

*void lista(int x){*

y quitar el return.